# Connecting Office 365 to multiple Azure Active Directories

Tags: active-directory, azure, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

I have an existing Office 365 subscription which is connected to an Azure Active Directory (I believe they all are by default).

I have a requirement to host another Azure Active Directory but need to give access to the same Office 365 subscription, is this supported ?

I've done some research and found plenty of content on synchronising multiple forests using ADFS etc. but that requires VM or on-prem AD which I don't want.

It feels like it should be possible since when I register a custom app on Azure Active Directory it's just a token provider.

Here's the background to the requirement, I've have two Active Directory Forests (which are actually exposed to the outside world via two instances of Dell Identity Manager) one for internal staff and one for external partners.

There's an existing subscription which the business is using and they have been using 'temporary solution' of giving external partner access to the site by using Live ID accounts for external partners.

I've been asked to bring this into line with company policy which is to use the corporate identity management system.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the requirement? Why do the two directories need to share the same subscription?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. I also suspect there might be some confusion leading you to think that this will address whatever may have prompted that requirement.

An Office 365 subscription is *contained* in the Azure AD directory, and licenses for that subscription can only be assigned to users of that directory.

Comment: I've logged a call with Microsoft Support but I suspect you maybe right, I guess the alternative would be to build out a new subscription with content for external partners only and secure access to this with a Azure AD Connect solution which merged both forests into the single AD directory.

Comment: One subscription will only be in one tenant. You won't be able to have two subscriptions on one directory either (well, you can, but the seats would just get pooled).

Comment: Yep understood, the staff account would have to appear in both subscriptions.